# Loop through Pandas data and find max value filter by 2 inputs(lat long)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

WE have some data from from NASA api for the brightest star, from the given data we have to find brightest star visible from a location, location we have to pass as lat long. the row which has max energy will be the brightest star.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

results=requests.get('https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/fireball.api?date-min=2017-01-01&date-max=2020-01-01&req-loc=true&limit=10')

parsed_data=results.text

final_data=json.loads(parsed_data)

#print(type(final_data["fields"]))
#print(type(final_data["data"]))

df = pd.DataFrame(final_data["data"],columns = final_data["fields"]) 
print(df.head())


                  date energy impact-e   lat lat-dir    lon lon-dir   alt   vel  
0  2019-12-21 14:30:52    6.5     0.21  56.5       N  147.6       W  35.5  22.2    
1  2019-12-11 01:19:11    3.9     0.13  47.7       N  161.7       E    37  17.8    
2  2019-12-06 10:19:57    4.6     0.15   3.3       S   37.7       W  19.5  None    
3  2019-12-03 06:46:27    4.2     0.14   5.6       N   52.2       W  61.5  None    
4  2019-11-28 20:30:54    2.7    0.095  35.7       N   31.7       W    35  13.0
```

I need A looping technique to take the input as lat long and based on that lat long find the brightest star.

Comment: Do you need to take multiple `lat-longs` as input? Or just one?

Answer (score 0):

To find the row with max `energy` value where `lat` and `long` matches:

```py
def find_brightest_star(df, lat, lon):
    try:
        idx = df[(df.lat.eq(lat)) & (df.lon.eq(lon))].energy.idxmax()
        return df.loc[idx]
    except:
        return 'No lat and long found in dataframe'
```

It'll return an message error if both `lat` and `lon` don't match the a row in the dataframe.

---

Example:

```py
df[['energy','lat','lon']] = df[['energy','lat','lon']].astype(float)
find_brightest_star(df, 56.5, 147.6)
```

Output:

```
date        2019-12-21 14:30:52
energy                      6.5
impact-e                   0.21
lat                        56.5
lat-dir                       N
lon                       147.6
lon-dir                       W
alt                        35.5
vel                        22.2
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

---

You can easily use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) inside the function, like:

```py
lat = float(input('Which is the latitude? '))
lon = float(input('Which is the longitude? '))
```

You'll probably wanna use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) as well.